# Angular - Check if page is refreshed or not

Tags: angular, typescript

is there with Angular a way to check if browser is refreshed or not? I need to check if page is refreshed or not...because if only the value is false I need to execute a function.

I have in an ngoninit a function like this:

```
pageIsRefreshed: Boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription.pipe(). subscribe(res=> {
 if(!pageIsRefreshed) { 
   dofunction();
  }
 })
}
```

But I can't find a solution to check if page is refreshed or not.

Comment: What do you mean by refreshed ?

Comment: @serrulien When I press F5 on browser or when page is loaded for the first time

Comment: What if the person pressed F5 and didn't do anything for 5 hours - is the page still considered refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

I pretty sure It's not possible to check if person has refreshed the page or not simply by using angular.

I would suggest that you store a session when the person is visting the page for the first time, then you could check if the page is refeshed or not by looking for session storage.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.pipe(). subscribe(res=> {
    const isPageRefreshed = session.getItem('isPageRefreshed');
    
    if(isPageRefreshed == 'true') { 
    
       dofunction();
    }
    // Visting the page first time
    else{
      session.getItem('isPageRefreshed','true');
    }
 })
}
```

Note: Do not forget to remove the session, when done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Router on angular for example:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      browserIsRefresh = !router.navigated;
    }
  });
}
```

when touter start is false and after first navigation is true.